# HTML I want links to open the content area?

Tags: php, html, css

I want fixed header does not go away when I click links from the navigation bar 
I was able to do that by dividing the page as table ,,

the problem is I want to know if this is possile or not I want the links in the navigation bar to open in the Right column the "content/the main colmn "

```
<!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->

<!-- ============ NAVIGATION BAR SECTION ============== -->
  link1 link2 link3 
<!-- ============ LEFT COLUMN (MENU) ============== -->
<!-- ============ RIGHT COLUMN (MENU) ============== -->

LINK1 WILL OPEN HERE ?? !! HOW USING TABLES TAGS OR DIV 



<!-- ============ FOOTER SECTION ============== -->
```

this is my try  but it does not work:

```
<li><a href="world.php" target="main" title="WORLD">WORLD</a></li>
```

please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible using Javascript. When creating your link, the href parameter would instead point to a javascript function which is responsible for loading the other page where you want it.

```
<a href="javascript:loadSideBar();">
```

Using a Javascript library like jQuery you can easily add cool effects as well.

Answer (score 0):

u can make the links to toggle hidden divs on their right places ,using javascript and jquery

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#main").click(function (){
           $("#side-menu").toggle('slow');
          });
         </script>
```

Comment: I want to try this but how to do it do you know some example or tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPage(page) {
$(".page").hide();
$("#" + page).show();
}
</script>
```

Links :

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="openPage(1);return false" title="WORLD">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="openPage(2);return false" title="WORLD">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="openPage(3);return false" title="WORLD">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="openPage(4);return false" title="WORLD">Page 4</a></li>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="page" id="1">
Page 1
</div>
<div class="page" id="2">
Page 2
</div>
<div class="page" id="3">
Page 3
</div>
<div class="page" id="4">
Page 4
</div>
```